# Periodically Notification for Document deletion

Tags: workflow, document-library, document-set, retention, 2016

I have a document library in SharePoint 2016.

What I Want is when I share any document to any user, that user should be notified periodically about time remaining for that Document expiration or deletion either by email or by default notification.

Can anyone help me out on the basis of SharePoint 2013 also?